# How to achieve lightening fast image download like Instagra

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, alamofire

I am making an app that displays images in tableViewCells similar to Instagram using Firebase as text based database and Amazon S3 as the storage for image file. I use Alamofire to download image in my app.

I was looking at the Instagram app and realized that they can display so many photos so quickly. I was wondering what is the general guide to achieve something like that? Taking into consideration of things like

1. When to start download the image?
2. Should the download stop at some point if required?
3. Is there ways to speed up the process with firebase, S3, Alamofire or is this combination doomed to be capped at an UN-satisifiable speed?
4. Caching image after download (already doing) and load from cache when possible)
5. How many parallel download should be going on at one time?

Note. I believe Instagram imags are 200kb~300kb each.